# c speed cython properties, possible? alternatives?

Tags: python, properties, cython, getter-setter

I have a python class which has a few properties. I converted the class to a cython extension type and defined the properties within it, using the cython syntax for properties http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/extension_types.html#properties. I see that properties have to be declared using def or I get a compile error "cdef statement not allowed here".

My class is also used within another cython module and I'd like to access properties from the class at c speed rather than python speed, otherwise it negates a bit the speedup I gain by using cython.  I know it would be faster if I use cdef setter and getter functions like get_params() and set_params(params) but if I do this change, then I would have to do it too in the python code (so that my python and cython code don't differ too much and can be compatible) but that makes the python code less readable.... dilemma!

is there a fast way to access properties in cython? or do you have any other suggestions so that I don't have to change my python code to use  setter and getter functions too?

Comment: yes I did, it gives exactly the same error "cdef statement not allowed here"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, since descriptors only exist at the Python level. Have your Cython code implement getters and setters, and create a Python type that exposes them via properties.

Comment: Or expose both from the same Cython class and leave the getters/setters undocumented (perhaps add a `_` prefix).

Comment: This could be an option. I would like to be able to run the python code without cython though

Answer (score 1):

To have the property available in both python & cython you have to make it public, example:

```
cdef class PyBrowser:
    cdef CefRefPtr[CefBrowser] cefBrowser

    cdef public dict clientCallbacks
    cdef public list allowedClientCallbacks
    IF CEF_VERSION == 1:
        cdef public JavascriptBindings javascriptBindings
    cdef public dict userData

    # Properties used by ToggleFullscreen().
    cdef public int isFullscreen
    cdef public int maximized
    cdef public int gwlStyle
    cdef public int gwlExStyle
    cdef public tuple windowRect
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. could you elaborate a bit more? I already have properties available both in python and cython but in cython they are accessed at python speed and what I want is to be able to access them fast, or an alternative

Comment: @martinako by defining "cdef public int isFullscreen" you can access it fast with C speed.

Comment: I'm not sure we are talking about the same type of properties. I'm referring to the syntax in here: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/extension_types.html#properties . If in the example in the link I try to apply what you say I would  add "cdef public object cheese" to the extension type definition but that gives a compile error